# Scaling up UI-Size of only one Monitor in a Multi-Monitor setup with KDE

Tags: kde, multi-monitor, resolution, plasma

so my problem is the following: I have two screens connected to my PC, one Full HD Monitor (on `HDMI-0`) and one 4k Monitor (on `DP-0`, both are connected directly to my GPU), i'd like to use the 4k Monitor in 4k Resolution, but have Text and UI size scaled up, so it is more readable.

First of all some general information about the system:

- OS: Manjaro (Kernel v. 5.15.21)
- Desktop environment: KDE Plasma v. 5.24.2 with KDE Frameworks v. 5.91.0
- (Edited) Display Manager: SDDM
- (Edited) GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (Driver v. 510.54)

The only option for this i found in my System Settings is to up the Global Scale, but upping that leads to the Text on my Full HD Monitor being way too big.

Another thing i've tried is forcing font DPI (in `Settings -> Appearance -> Fonts`) with (almost) the same effect as changing the Global Scale.

I also tried `xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --scale 0.5x0.5 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 960x2160 --scale 1x1 --primary`  (`DP-0` is the 4k Monitor), but that leads to the Monitor being (very) blurry and the monitor arrangement being kind of screwed (which i know could be fixed by passing positional arguments to `xrandr`, but since it's blurry anyway it doesn't really matter right now). Doing something similar with `--transform` instead of `--scale` (`xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --transform 0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,1 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 960x2160 --transform 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 --primary`) lead to the same issue. Also setting the global scale to 200% and scaling down the Full HD monitor (with `xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --scale 1x1 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 960x2160 --scale 2x2 --primary` or `xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --transform 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 960x2160 --transform 2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1 --primary`) fixes the blurriness issue on the 4k Screen, but the Full HD Screen is now blurry and the taskbar and Desktop on the Full HD Screen is now cut in half.

So is there any "good" way to change the scaling for only my 4k Monitor in KDE? I vaguely remember having an option for this in Gnome (but not having used it, since my old PC didn't support 4k@60Hz anyway), so it would be nice to be able to do this in KDE as well.

Comment: Thought KDE might be the solution to the fractional scaling in Gnome Wayland, but this multi monitor issue here is nearly equally annoying. Why exactly is Microsoft Windows a role model in this cases? Can't believe it!